# A downloadable PDF from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database table which stores the document file name and on the local pc i have a folder named as **uploads** which stores the actual files the user uploads.

The way i upload files are as follows,

```
$filename = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
    
    // destination of the file on the server
    $destination = 'uploads/' . $filename;
    
    // get the file extension
    $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    
    // the physical file on a temporary uploads directory on the server
    $file = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
    $size = $_FILES['attachment']['size'];
    
    if (!in_array($extension, ['zip', 'pdf', 'docx'])) {
      echo "You file extension must be .zip, .pdf or .docx";
    } elseif ($_FILES['attachment']['size'] > 1000000) { // file shouldn't be larger than 1Megabyte
      echo "File too large!";
    } else {
      // move the uploaded (temporary) file to the specified destination
      if (move_uploaded_file($file, $destination)) {
        
        $sender_name = $_POST['sender_name'];
        $contact = $_POST['contactnumber'];
        $sender_mail = $_POST['sender_email'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $applied = date('Y-m-d');
        
        $jobapply = "INSERT INTO `job_submission`(`NAME`, `CONTACT`, `EMAIL`, `MESSAGE`, 
 `APPLIED_ON`, `CAREER_ID`,`CV`) VALUES 
 ('$sender_name','$contact','$sender_mail','$description','$applied','$idc','$filename')";
        
        if (mysqli_query($connect, $jobapply)) {
          echo "You Application Was Submitted Successfully! We Wish You All The Best";
        }
      } else {
        echo "Failed to upload file.";
      }
    }
```

The results of this code is the file name along with the other data are stored in the database and on the other hand the file is also stored in the uploads directory.
[image: Database Data]
[image: Local PC]

Now i want to download the file stored in the folder to the machine by using a button. for which I have written a code as follows,

```
 if (isset($_GET['file_id'])) {
 $id = $_GET['file_id'];
 // fetch file to download from database
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM job_submission WHERE JOB_ID='$id'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
 $file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 $filepath = 'uploads/' . $file['CV'];
 if (file_exists($filepath)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filepath));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('uploads/' . $file['CV']));
    readfile('uploads/' . $file['CV']);
    exit;
}
}
```

The above code is called from a button inside a table,

```
<td><a href="careers.php?file_id=<?php echo $rowselect['JOB_ID'] ?>">Download</a> </td>
```

The file gets downloaded but it doesn't open and throws an error saying

> Error Failed to load PDF document.

Comment: that code is looking for a uploads folder in your webserver document root, not a folder somewhere in your _local_ computer

Comment: @LelioFaieta I dont have the site hosted its still under the localhost. If you are reffering the line `readfile('uploads/' . $file['name']);` even if i change the location to the exact folder as `C:\wamp64\www\HR\uploads` it still downloads the very same document but throws unable to open the pdf error when trying to open

Comment: Small Edit 
$file['name'] should be $file['CV']
Question Edited

Comment: When i open the downloaded PDF file with notepad it give me this (Attching G Drive link since document content is very long) 
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UjyEH9QVPxV68JVDA4JNfrcr7Myk6NaP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you need to move the pdf to *a folder named upload* inside your document root, you are trying to access something that is outside the document root. Even if it is inside your pc you will have a folder where all your project files are and there you need to put the upload folder with the files

Comment: And see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound/executed queries

Comment: @LelioFaieta I am sorry but i am unable to figure out what the Document Root of the uploads directory is, The strucutre of the project is www/HR/code_files under this HR folder I have the folder uploads. this specific code to store the file is under the code file of careerdetails.php. Even if i move the uploads folder under WWW it throws error saying no such files or directory
Any documentations or tutorials would be much appreciated